# Stock Price Date adjusting in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to ask about how to adjust (delete non-duplicated ones) dates in stock prices of two different companies using pandas.

I have downloaded stock prices via [from yahoo_finance import Share] and let it be saved as pickle. And each "len" of dataset says different length just as I expected.

The thing is that when I have historical stock prices data of a company in Japan and one another in France, they must have different holidays so that they show different volume of dataset even for the same period of time. I used to do it manually in excel if I had only small number of companies, but as the number of companies I want to compare increases, I can't just do it in this way.

How can I remove only the rows that "do not share the same dates" with one another? I already have 'Date' as one of the columns.

I belive there must be some ways to manage this trouble, for this is what people who deal with financial time series datawould have to do everytime, I guess...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `date`s have been parsed as Timestamps:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
```

Set the `date` column as the index:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('date')
df2 = df2.set_index('date')
```

Find the intersection of the indexes:

```
index = (df1.index).intersection(df2.index)
```

Reindex the DataFrames to the common dates:

```
df1 = df1.reindex(index)
df2 = df2.reindex(index)
```